# How to convert SAP MTA (Multi target application) into a Maven project?

Tags: maven, sapui5

I have exported a MTA project created in SAP Web IDE. Now I have imported this in Eclipse and want to build it using Maven. How do I do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on scenarios.MTA project consists of the different module having the same application lifecycle but they are not multiple module maven projects.If u have only a JAVA project you can manually convert it into maven project by changing manifest.yml as deployment descriptor file instead of mta.yml.Could you elaborate your scenario little bit?

Comment: I have a DB, some NodeJS and OData services,  UI module and a site-content module. This entire collection can be built by just selecting the top level folder in WebIDE. I want to do the same thing locally. I have exported the Project artifacts now and imported the zip in Eclipse. Right now I need to convert each module of the project into a maven project so that I can build it using Maven in Eclipse. How shall I proceed ?

Comment: Mtar and maven projects are two different technologies.Maven is used mainly for  developing JAVA app and mtar for MTAs.You can see build results with full-stack web ide. don't think you do that in a automate way.the only way manually converts it to muiti-module maven project by creating pom.xml .

Comment: Yes I am aware that mtar and Maven are two different things. If you go through maven's docs you'll know that we can specify our own custom archiving formats. mtar happens to be one such format. archiving a Maven project into mtar is no big deal. What I wanted to know was, what changes (if any) needs to added to pom.xml for all the modules before I archive them into mtar ?

Comment: No changes at all because Web IDE even uses maven internally to create war files foe JAVA.I am afraid how modules other than java can build using Maven.

Comment: Well it could be done. Many teams are doing it so I guess it is possible